# Call function/Sub in code vba

Tags: excel, vba, rounding, truncate

I wrote a code in VBA that takes values from a workbook and copies them to another workbook. So for instance in cell G20 I will have  45 678
The code then rounds this number to 46 000, and then I need a function to delete the last 3 figures if the number is big enough using the If statement provided below.
I think the content is right but I don't think I am calling it the right way.

```
DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(tax_declaration.Worksheets(1)Range("I72").Value, -3)
DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G11").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Val(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("I25:I27"))), -3)

Call thousand(DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10"))

End Sub

Sub thousand(i As Variant)

If Right(i, 3) = "000" Then
  i = Left(i, Len(i) - 3)
End If

End Sub`
```

How could I create a function like my If statement, and use it to Loop through all my 'DSA.Worksheets(1)Ranges' ? - I have several of those.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean - loop through all the worksheets? Or loop through multiple ranges in the same worksheet?

Comment: I meant loop through multiple ranges in the same worksheet, sorry if it wasnt clear !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean but instead of the sub just use a function and pass different i:

```
Function thousand(i As Variant) As Variant

If Right(i, 3) = "000" Then
  thousand = Left(i, Len(i) - 3)
End If

End Function
```

Then you just do something along the lines of `debug.print thousand(DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10"))`

Comment: When I try to run the marco I get an error message saying "Argument not optional" for thousand. I changed the function to declare thousand as a Variant as well but i still get "argument not optional for `Debug.Print thousand(DSA.Worksheets(1).Range("G10"))`   Do you know why ? I think I may need to add a 'Set' somewhere !